# "ViewManagerAdapter_ExpoLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, expo, gradient, linear-gradients

I am using Expo 44. The project works fine for android. But for IOS, it gives a strange error:

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ViewManagerAdapter_ExpoLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager.

I have done "expo install expo-linear-gradient" & "yarn add expo-linear-gradient". Also added the pod:

```
pod 'ExpoLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios'
```

But none of it helps. Can someone please suggest a way out of this?

Answer (score 3):

hope you've resolve your reported error with `expo-linear-gradient` above?

If haven't, I downgraded the latest 11.0.3 package version to the 10.0.3 version - rebuild both ios, android and now error resolved.

for example in `package.json` file:

```
"expo-linear-gradient": "10.0.3",
```

[npm expo-linear-gradient releases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29zWl.png)